# Bionic upgrades don’t work

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I’m running Lubuntu on a MacBook Pro 2011 with a burnt graphics card. I managed 2 years ago to switch it completely to Lubuntu Xenial and it all worked fine until I upgraded to Bionic Beaver last year. All still works fine except for the software updates which haven’t updated even once since the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.

In the Terminal I do a `sudo apt-get update` (runs fine) followed by an `apt-get upgrade`. I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.neterra.net/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.neterra.net/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.neterra.net/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.neterra.net/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Graphic interface works similarly. In **Software Updater** I get a "*The software of this computer is up-to-date*" message, which it definitely cannot be.

I suppose there's a broken repository link but I can't figure this out by myself. How do I solve this issue?

My configuration is:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**Computer:**
Processor       : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2635QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
Memory      : 3949MB (2219MB used)
Machine Type        : Notebook
Operating System        : Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)
User Name       : bo (bo)
Date/Time       : Sun 07 Jul 2019 15:20:41 EEST

**Display:**
Resolution      : 1440x900 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : (Unknown)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation

**Audio Devices:**
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH

**Operating System:**
Kernel      : Linux 4.15.0-13-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #14-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 17 13:44:27 UTC 2018
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-0ubuntu3) 2.27
Distribution        : Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)

Added **apt history log:**

```
~$ less /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

> Start-Date: 2019-07-07  16:51:35
>
> Commandline: apt full-upgrade
>
> Requested-By: bo (1000)
>
> Install: linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-54-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-54.58,
>   automatic), libwayland-egl1:amd64 (1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1,
>   automatic), intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20190618.0ubuntu0.18.04.1,
>   automatic), networkd-dispatcher:amd64 (1.7-0ubuntu3.3, automatic),
>   python3-dateutil:amd64 (2.6.1-1, automatic), libllvm8:amd64
>   (1:8-3~ubuntu18.04.1, automatic),
>   linux-modules-4.15.0-54-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-54.58, automatic),
>   libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.3-1ubuntu1.2, automatic),
>   linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-54.58, automatic),
>   iucode-tool:amd64 (2.3.1-1, automatic), libwoff1:amd64
>   (1.0.2-1build0.1, automatic), ...
>
> ...
>
> ...shim:amd64 (13-0ubuntu2, 15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1)
>
> End-Date: 2019-07-08  00:10:23

```
~$ less /var/log/apt/history.log.2.gz
```

> Start-Date: 2019-06-16  17:26:50
>
> Commandline: /usr/sbin/synaptic
>
> Requested-By: bo (1000)
>
> Install: libopencore-amrnb0:amd64 (0.1.3-2.1,automatic), libopencore-amrwb0:amd64 (0.1.3-2.1, automatic), gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 (1.14.0-1, automatic), libsidplay1v5:amd64(1.36.59-11, automatic), soundconverter:amd64 (3.0.0-2), gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 (1.14.0-1, automatic)
>
> End-Date:
>   2019-06-16  17:31:06

```
~$ less /var/log/apt/history.log.3.gz
```

> Start-Date: 2019-04-08  22:45:52
>
> Commandline: apt install debian-keyring
>
> Requested-By: bo (1000)
>
> Install: debian-keyring:amd64 (2018.03.24)
>
> End-Date: 2019-04-08  22:46:41

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt update` and followed that up  with `sudo apt full-upgrade`? Also try changing your server to the main server rather than what you have (mirrors.neterra.net).

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1156548/edit) your question to show us the complete output of this command: `tail -n20 /var/log/apt/history.log`. It simply displays the last 20 lines of that particular logfile.

Comment: Thanks @DK Bose, `sudo apt update` followed by `apt full-upgrade` did not make any change. Changing the server and then running the update/full-upgrade got the system to upgrade 794 packages. It’s still underway. I think this should do the job.

Comment: @user535733, I ran the command but it listed an unreasonably large number of lines to add them to my question (I'm only afraid this may look like spamming the topic but I can't really judge). If you think this would add to the value of this please let me know and I'll add it. Before the big chunk starts I get the following output: >~$ tail -n20 /var/log/apt/history.log

Start-Date: 2019-07-07  16:51:35
Commandline: apt full-upgrade
Requested-By: bo (1000)

Comment: You are correct - you are offering to post history of what happened earlier today. We don't want that. Use the `less` command to browse through your history.log.1.gz file  (`less /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`) for events and upgrades from last month. Tell us if the file is empty, or if it has lots of entries. If it has lots of entries, tell us a couple dates with lots of actiity.

Comment: I posted a little more than you asked for, @user535733, as I was a little confused with the outputs. The `less /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz` today gave me the output of yesterday's `tail -n20 /var/log/apt/history.log` because I may have messed with the **history.log**. I need to do my reading on this topic. I had not used this machine for months as I was aware it did not update properly and I didn't have the time to deal with it. This is why you see the gaps. history.log.4.gz dates to December 2018 but it's huge and I didn't post it.

Comment: Looks like you have been upgrading occasionally (good). Do you [have unattended-upgrades enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916722)?

Comment: I have just become aware of unattended-upgarding from your question. It looks like it's not been enabled on my computer (`cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` returned _No such file or directory_) but `tail /var/log/dpkg.log` returned a list of 10 items updated today - I made manual updates today using apt-get.